# Analyzing a special case of the Big O notation for N->R and g(n) =/= 0

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, computer-science

It's my first post here so be gentle ^^

My problem formulates like this:

Given the functions $f,g:\mathbb {N} \to \mathbb {R_0^+}$ with the property $g(n) \not = 0 \ \ \ \forall n\in \mathbb {N}$, is the following equivalence true ?

$∃α > 0 : ∀n ∈ N : f(n) ≤ α · g(n)$

$\Leftarrow\Rightarrow$

$f \in\{f \ | \ ∃\ α > 0 , ∃ \ n_0 ∈ \mathbb{N} \ , \  ∀n ≥ n_0 : 0 ≤ f (n) ≤ αg(n)\}$ (This set will be reffered to as $O(g)$)

Since this is all quite theoretical I tried to make a case and get a feel for the problem.

So I asked my self a new question:

Given that $1/x \leqslant x+c$ with $c$ being some constant, holds for all $x\geqslant 1+c$ we know $\\$ $f(x)=1/x$ and $g(x)=x+c$  suffices $f \in O(g) $ with $n_0 = 1$, we should be able to pinpoint the biggest $f(x)$ for $x<1$ as the superior of the following set:
$I:=\{f(x) \ : \ f <g \text{ with } x >1 \ \land f <g \text{ with } x <1 \}$
Let`s call $sup(I)$ = $\epsilon$

With the help of $\epsilon$ it should be possible to somehow algeabraically find an $\alpha$ so that $\alpha g(x) = \epsilon$
How the algebra works in that case is not interesting to my problem but if that holds $f$ and $g$ suffice the first part of the equivalence on the top. And that would be the first step to get a proof for general $f$ and $g$ sufficing said equivalence.

Thank you for reading and I`m looking forward to creating a nice proof with you guys

Comment: I have to confess I don't understand how your 'new question' is going to help you with the problem at hand. An equivalence is sometimes such that one implication is easy, the other more complicated. That's true here as well, with the easy part being $\Rightarrow$. Can you start with a proof of that and then maybe think about the other direction?

Comment: @Ingix Would you have a look at the answer I gave myself? Not toally sure it works like that and would appreciate a 2nd opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

For the stray soul who will be needing an answer in the future like I did in the past:

Let $f,g :\mathbb{N \to R_0^+} \text{ and } g(n) \not = 0 
,∀n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Then :
$f \in O(g)<==> ∃\ α > 0 : ∀n \in \mathbb{N}: f(n)≤α*g(n) $

Proof:$  \  $
"==>"

Let $ f \in O(g)$
<==>$ ∃ n_0 \in \mathbb{N} , ∃ α > 0 :0≤f(n)≤ g(n)*α ,\forall n≥ n_0 \ $

Let $N := \{n < n_0\}$, $N$ contains $n_0$ elements and is therefore finite.
Let $m_f = max ( f(N))$ and $m_g = min (g(N))$

Then : $\frac{1}{m_f} *f(N)≤1 $ and $m_g * g(n)≤1 $

Therefore is $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$\frac{1}{m_f}*f(n)≤m_g *g(n) <==> f(n)≤m_f *m_g*g(n) $

Choosing $\beta = max(\alpha , m_g*m_f$

Then: $0 ≤ f(n) ≤ \beta *g(n), \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

"<==":

Let $∃\ α > 0 : ∀n \in \mathbb{N}$ be true:

Going after the premise: $f(n) ≥ 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Then for $n_0=0$:
$\exists \alpha > 0 : 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ \alpha * g(n)$

$End$ $ of$ $ Proof$

Comment: Proof is correct, with a minor clerical error: I think you mean $m_g = \min(\frac1{g(N)})$ and then it follows for $n \in N: m_gg(n) \ge 1$, which you need in the next step.